# In Loadrunner - Unable start executing script with Goal oriented scenario

Tags: loadrunner

In Loadrunner - Unable start executing script with Goal oriented scenario in basic schedule mode. Error occurred " loadrunner cannot create vusers, ensure your load generator available and that your script is valid"

Kindly advice whether we could not use basic schedule in "Goal oriented scenario". If not, please help how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to start a single user even without a goal oriented scenario?

My hypothesis is that this has less to do with the use of Goal Oriented Scenario and is more likely related to other items, such as electing a load generator which is not configured with proper software, use of a script with no transaction markers, etc....

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt if you can connect to your load generator, click on scenario > load generators and check if you are able to connect to Load generators.